# Better alt+tab for Gnome?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

Is there any <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> module for gnome that make it behave more like it is in Windows 7?

**Edit**: By how it behaves more like Windows 7, I mean when you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> you can also, when you have those keys pressed in, navigate through the windows with the arrow keys

Comment: Compiz takes anything you've ever dreamed of other operating system and lets you tear it down and reconstruct it to your own will.
Play with it, look on forums, change it.

It's easy: take a function of any kind and search it on google.

e.g.
aero snap ubuntu

wham: done :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure ubuntu comes with compiz by default

Comment: except for http://askubuntu.com/questions/37335/drag-and-drop-across-fullscreen-applications-switching-via-alt-tab

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can customise window switching using [CompizConfig Settings Manager (CCSM)](http://wiki.compiz.org/CCSM) [image: install compizconfig-settings-manager].

If you launch CCSM, you will find the relevant options (highlighted) in the 'Window Management' section. The 'Switcher' options are all a variation on the traditional <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> behaviour but they are much more customisable and you can use any keyboard shortcut you want.

[image: ccsm main window]

You can enable them by ticking the checkbox next to the option. Click on the option to configure it. To get <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> behaviour you need to set the keyboard shortcut for the 'Next Window' action to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

[image: Options for shift switcher]

To set the keyboard shortcut, click the button to the right of 'Next Window' and follow the dialog to grab the key combination that can be <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or any other combination you prefer.

[image: Edit Next Window Dialog]

You may use any number of these window switchers but you must use different keyboard shortcuts so that they don't conflict.

As for:

> make it behave more like it is in Windows 7

I have never used this operating system so I don't know how it behaves. I assume it is a window switcher with eye candy - this is what these Compiz Plugins provide.

**Note:** you need to run Compiz (desktop effects) for this solution to work. This requires the appropriate drivers and a sufficient graphics card to work.

Answer (score 4):

With Compiz (the the well known window manager with composition), you may use any key/mouse combination (not only alt-tab> to switch between windows (there are many plugins included with Compiz that may change the behavior).

To install Compiz (supposing that your video card is compiz-capable):

sudo apt-get install compiz compizconfig-settings-manager

Once installed, goto "System" -> "Preferences" -> "CompizConfig Settings Manager", and start playing with it!

Answer (score 2):

I think that

> behave like Windows7

means to allow browsing through available windows (after <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is pressed) using arrow-keys, <kbd>Page Up</kbd>, <kbd>Page Down</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, mouse etc.

I have tried to solve this but the only **compiz** module (compiz=window manager in Gnome) which supports this feature is the *shift switcher* (maybe *ring switcher* supports it to).

It seems that the **traditional window switchers** (flat overview of windows composed in a table, without animations) such as *Static App. Switcher* or *App. Switcher* **don't support** this behavior.

To set up those switchers in Gnome (compiz), use CompizConfig Settings Manager (CCSM) (might be necessary to install it). For details about CCSM see the answer of [dv3500ea](https://askubuntu.com/a/32000/14841).

On the other hand, you could try **kde4** which supports this feature.

Or you can use [Gnome-Shell](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell) [image: install gnome-shell] which also supports this app-switching behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a fan of compiz, so I have another solution that has worked fine for me for years.
It's a little app called [*"Super Switcher"*](http://code.google.com/p/superswitcher/).

Make sure you get the .6 version, errors will occur on the .5 version.

It works great on laptops. All you have to do is hold the <kbd>Super</kbd> down and <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd>. To move a window between desktops, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd>.

So easy.

Answer (score 1):

I searched and searched for an answer to a similar question and wasn't satisfied with anything I found until I came across this on [this blog](https://people.gnome.org/~federico/blog/alt-tab.html).  Simply execute these commands in a shell:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications "[]"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications-backward "[]"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows "['<Alt>Tab', '<Super>Tab']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows-backward  "['<Alt><Shift>Tab', '<Super><Shift>Tab']"
```

The result is that you will be able to switch between all windows (including those from the same app) with alt+tab (and alt+shift+tab) much like in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try compiz-settings-manager... there you have some options to chage between windows.... don't know if you'll think it behaves like Windows 7, but give it a try and customize it to your like.