# Holding Click On Window Titlebar While Changing Workspaces in 11.04

Tags: 11.04, keyboard, workspaces, shortcuts

In previous versions of Ubuntu, I could click and hold on a window's titlebar and then use my hot key combination to switch to a different workspace and the window would come with me.  However, in 11.04, if I try this, the keyboard switching hot key appears to be disabled once I have clicked on the titlebar. I understand that I can use keyboard shortcuts or right click the titlebar, to move a window to a specific workspace. However, I prefer the other behavior and am curious if there is anyway to get it to work.

Comment: wondering if this is related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/37335/drag-and-drop-across-fullscreen-applications-switching-via-alt-tab

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can live with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Arrow</kbd> to move the current window to another workspace?

Comment: As I stated before, I know I can use keyboard commands.  I am trying to habituate to the change, but I do prefer the other behavior.