# Drag And Drop in Unity (with Alt + Tab)

Tags: unity, drag-and-drop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Drag and Drop across (fullscreen) applications, switching via Alt-Tab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37335/drag-and-drop-across-fullscreen-applications-switching-via-alt-tab)

I would like to be able to drag files from one window (nautilus) to another switching app with Alt + Tab.

Is that possible?