# Desktop environments that allow Drag'n'Drop across applications via Alt-Tab

Tags: usability, drag-and-drop, task-management, application-switcher

Which desktop environments allow to drag'n'drop files/data across applications while task-switching using Alt-Tab (without the need to move mouse cursor to a specific UI element and/or wait for other UI elements to become active)?

To the best of my knowledge:

Working

- Unity 2D of Ubuntu 11.04 (as using Metacity)
  https://askubuntu.com/questions/44168/does-dragndrop-across-applications-while-switching-tasks-via-alt-tab-work-in-un
- xmonad on Kubuntu 11.04 (as of answer below, thanks)

Not working:

- Unity (3D) of Ubuntu 11.04 (as using Compiz)
  [Drag and Drop across (fullscreen) applications, switching via Alt-Tab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37335/drag-and-drop-across-fullscreen-applications-switching-via-alt-tab)
- Unity 2D of Ubuntu 11.10
- Unity (3D) of Ubuntu 11.10
- gnome-shell of Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: How do you perform this acrobatic trick - Drag-and-Drop without moving mouse (i.e. without dragging?) I thought you would need to press down mouse button and start moving the mouse to initiate dragging... I did a test and it worked for me in XMonad, but maybe I'm doing it wrong as I'm not sure I didn't move my mouse.

Comment: you're so right! we have to move mouse a bit to start dragging -- but apart from that pixel ...?

Answer (score 1):

It does work in Xmonad running on Kubuntu 11.04 - I'm not sure whether XMonad or KWin responsible for Drag'n'Drop behaviour in this case.

Comment: I haven't tried XMonad, but I use KWin and I have this feature as of Kubuntu 13.04 (and it's been there at least since 11.10, I don't remember before that)