# Why is alt+tab not working when dragging out of Firefox?

Tags: 18.04, application-switcher, drag-and-drop

In contrast to [previous Ubuntu versions](https://askubuntu.com/q/37335/161463), <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> while dragging seems to work fine in Ubuntu 18.04. For instance, I can start dragging a file, <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to a different application, and drop the file there.

However, <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> isn't working for me though, if the dragging source is Firefox. For instance, after I start dragging the browser URL (or any other random page text), pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> has no effect whatsoever. I can no longer switch to the target application, which makes drag&drop quite invonvenient. Doing exactly the same from Google Chrome works fine.

Any ideas why this is happening and how it can be fixed?

---

Some details:

- Firefox version is <s>`69.0.2`</s> <s>`83.0`</s> `84.0`. I'm observing this behavior for a very long time already (~2+ years). It is not specific to the Firefox version.
- Dragging within Firefox itself works: I can for instance drag page text to the browser URL field.
- I cannot say for sure if Firefox is the only application showing this effect, but at least it is the only one from my everyday applications in which dragging messes up <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>.

Comment: probably an unwanted change inside Firefox settings, which one? idk

Comment: @damadam: I have checked `about:config` and almost all settings (in particular settings matching "drag") are at default. I've also disabled all addons. Hard to say what could be the cause.