# Dragging and dropping across full screen applications in Gnome in 20.04

Tags: gnome, 20.04, application-switcher, drag-and-drop

I remember that before upgrading from 16.04 to 20.04 I used to be able to drag and drop across applications that are each in full screen, by using the application switching mechanism (Alt-tabbing), or by temporary hovering over the icon of a running application which would then get the focus.

In 20.04  I tried both means, in addition to attempting to switch directly to the desired target application by pressing Super+num, but to no avail.

It seems that all application switching mechanisms get disabled while a drag is in progress.

Is there a way to make that work? Or to practically achieve the same result in a usable way? Are any related bugs pending?

Question [#37335](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37335) seems to be a similar or related.

Comment: Works for me on 20.04. I can, for example, drag a text file from Files, then with the mouse button held, Alt+Tab to Firefox and drop the file there.

Comment: I am with OP, I cannot drag and drop, also alt tab switch does not work while I am holding the file